# Hochschild homology and Chern character quiver with potential

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, quivers, hochschild-homology

I am a beginner in quiver theory so this question might not be suitable for mathoverflow.

Let $(Q,W)$ be a quiver with potential and let $\Gamma$ be the Ginzburg DG-algebra associated to $(Q,W)$. Is there a "down-to-earth" way to compute the Hochschild homology of $\Gamma$? Furthermore, is there a *Chern character map* from $D_{fd}(\Gamma)$ to $\mathrm{HH}_0(\Gamma)$? Is it possible to describe explicitely this Chern character for the simple projective objects of rank $1$ associated to the vertices of $Q$?

Tanks in advance!